# JNI function table - functions' implementation in Dalvik source code

Tags: android, java-native-interface, interpreter, dalvik

I'm trying to find the entry point to Dalvik's interperter loop.

I've read the Android (2.1 froyo) boot-up code up to the point where "env->CallStaticVoidMethod()" is called. This means "start running a JAVA static void method in Dalvik". In my case the specified method is the ZygoteInit's main method.

However, I cannot find the c/cpp implementation of this entry method ("CallStaticVoidMethod") anywhere in the code - only references and declerations.

The same goes to all of the other interpreter entry points - CallObjectMethod, CallBooleanMethod, etc...

In the file dalvik/vm/Jni.c of the source code, there is a global variable gNativeInterface which holds pointers to all of these functions. It is initialized with symbols that I cannot find the definitions of (I suspect this is because some Macro was used to define them).

Thanks up front to all repliers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CallStaticVoidMethod() is implemented via a macro in [dalvik/vm/Jni.c](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/dalvik.git;a=blob;f=vm/Jni.c)
(a header file first maps CallStaticVoidMethod to CallStaticVoideMethodV)

```
2893 /*
2894  * Call a static method.
2895  */
2896 #define CALL_STATIC(_ctype, _jname, _retfail, _retok, _isref)               \

2912     static _ctype CallStatic##_jname##MethodV(JNIEnv* env, jclass jclazz,   \
2913         jmethodID methodID, va_list args)                                   \
2914     {                                                                       \
2915         UNUSED_PARAMETER(jclazz);                                           \
2916         JNI_ENTER();                                                        \
2917         JValue result;                                                      \
2918         dvmCallMethodV(_self, (Method*)methodID, NULL, true, &result, args);\
2919         if (_isref && !dvmCheckException(_self))                            \
2920             result.l = addLocalReference(env, result.l);                    \
2921         JNI_EXIT();                                                         \
2922         return _retok;                                                      \
2923     }                                                                    

2945 CALL_STATIC(void, Void, , , false);
```

dvmCallMethodV is implemented in [davlik/vm/interp/Stack.c](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/dalvik.git;a=blob;f=vm/interp/Stack.c)